# Best way to implement an application with webservices available for the customer, also getting information from webservices from 3rd party

Tags: .net, web-services, logging, transactions

For one of our customers we have to build an application to order documents at a printing office. We are the party in between the client and the printing office.

We start with a set of documents that is available on our own server. We will update the information of these documents with an excel that will be provided by the customer. Everything will be stored in our database. 
The client can update documents or mark them as invalid, and this will be done by calling webservices at our end.

The client will also send us orders that were made by their customers. We will update the order information and then send the document with the information to the printing office. The printing office has his own webservices for this. We cannot ask the printing office to gives us updates of the order, so we need to pull this information from the printing office itself and give this information to our client by calling webservices at their side.

The documents will be placed on our server and we will need to process an excel to put the information of these documents in the database. When ready the content managers can take a look at it and then do the manual updates for each document. This by entering data for each document into a form in a web application.

Our content managers should also be able to see the orders, track orders, get information of the orders in our back-end.

We will also need some serious logging and be able to track all steps in this process. 
At our side there will also be a webapplication with forms to do some manual input on the documents and to retrieve information about the orders.

Now we are looking for the best solution on how to implement such a system: with scheduled tasks, with a "framework": spring.net? nservicebus? Windows Foundation? Windows services?

Comment: the question you ask is very vague to be answered in SO. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Answer (score 2):

**You're describing the architecture.**

Your question contains a good description of the software architecture. It's good as overview, but the actual implementation needs more details, which cannot be discussed online. For example throughput and latency could be important to determine the proper technology. Thus you won't get a precise answer here.

**Look for existing skills.**

I assume that the development team is already lined up. Did you ask them for their experience? They probably will have their own opinion on what technology to use. May it's not the best of breed solution, but it's the best solution you will get with the existing team.

**Proof of concept.**

Create a minimal solution first and test if it fits your requirements. As you mentioned, start with a set of unmodifiable documents on your servers. Publish it as a productive system before continuing with more features. You'll get a good feeling if it is capable for future extensions. You cannot be totally ignorant about the next steps, but it's easier to adjust on the way rather than planning every detail at the beginning.

**Loose coupling.**

To make adjustments easier, keep components as loosely coupled as possible.
For example there will be one document component, one Excel processing component, ...
This makes it easier to change parts of the system if they won't fit
the requirements anymore.

**...**

This might not be the answer you wanted, but if project management would be that easy, everybody would do it. Another hint: maybe you'll realize one day that webservices aren't the best solution and you need an asynchronous messaging system. Therefore start small and adjust fast.

Comment: I like this answer best. Agreed that the question is high level, and this answer matches that profile. Spring.NET and an MVC/Web API setup are possible as well. If anyone could point out other helpful tools: thats welcome as well! (eg: Mass Transit, or NServicebus, ...)

Answer (score 1):

There are certain components of your requirements that require timer

> We cannot ask the printing office to gives us updates of the order, so
>   we need to pull this information from the printing office itself and
>   give this information to our client by calling webservices at their
>   side.

and you also mentioned that you need some user interface for

> Our content managers should also be able to see the orders, track
>   orders, get information of the orders in our back-end.

Like what @Chris had mentioned, there's no best solution when your questions are so high level.

### Getting everyone on the same page

For a start, you should at least visualize your problems and proposed solutions, minimally in mock-ups or screenflows (doesn't need to be nice and complete). At least, these mock-ups can be used as a baseline or even part of the sign-off.

As for development "frameworks", there are many options available out there that are good in their own ways, you can use some [ORM tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to speed up development

### Quick & easy development :

Entity framework 6 - Developed by Microsoft themselves that boasts about fluent interaction with database & code-first approach, which promises minimal DB interaction for developers.
The catch is, it gives poor performance compared to others

There are tons of alternatives like Nhibernate, nHydrate or micro ORMS like active records & [dapper.net (by stackoverflow guys)](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

### Determine your timeline

How long do you have to deliver the project? Do you want to include architecture patterns like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection or quality assurance processes unit-testing and continuous integration? Is it worth the budget? Do you have enough time?

### Maintenance

Are you going to maintain this application? Try to do proper logging, exception handling before the poop hits the fan and get's everyone cursing.

The bulk of your question describes your 'to-do' list, but there are many other omitted yet critical description of your "Question", the tag you used are also misleading.

**So my answer for "Best way to implement an application with web services available for the customer" is:**

Use .net MVC5, which comes with WebAPI 2, it can easily help you create web services, and with MVC, isolation of responsibility is part of the design. UI generation is easy, if you understand HTML.

Quick and dirty vs slow and clean is your choice :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer to this question has vast possibilities, the framework can be definite. You should be using **Spring.net framework** with WCF services support.

Benefits that Spring.NET will give you are as below:

- Inversion of Control (IoP)
- Aspect-oriented programming (AOP)
- Solid enterprise libraries that make persistence, transactions, web UI, services, etc. easier.

It will guide to building **understandable**, **testable** and **maintainable** web services, by moving out almost all infrastructural code from presentation and domain objects; Which means that you can easily and reliably make changes to the code. It is non-obtrusive; gives you all the freedom you need.

I think the biggest reason is the rigor you can apply to design, implementation, and testing. The code you write is far better than anything you might roll on my own. I've found that projects have benefited a great deal from using Spring. My understanding and thinking has been influenced, too.

References:

- http://www.springframework.net/doc-1.1-M2/reference/html/webservices.html
- http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html